# Creating a method in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

Hi I am doing a condition which I just want to call a method if the condition is true, the problem is I cannot find the syntax how to create a method in C-Lisp I am new with this language here's the code.

```
/* I want to create a method here which i can all anytime in my condition but I am having problem with a syntax 

 (void method()
   (print "Invalid")
 )

*/

(print "Enter number") 
(setq number(read())
(cond((< 1 number) (print "Okay"))
     ((> 1 number) /*I want to call a method here (the invalid one)*/ )
)
```

Comment: What is `void` supposed to do? See `defmethod` for method of `defun` for function (doesn't have type overload)

Comment: I would also suggest that you look into the condition system.  Here is a link to get you started http://gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-exception-handling-conditions-and-restarts.html#conditions

Comment: Davids comment is about actual lisp conditions, which are like exceptions in other languages but with more power. I detect you probably know a programming language already, perhaps one of the C family languages. It's difficult to assimilate your first lisp on algol knowledge so it's better to play green and go for a tutorial or book right away.

Comment: What happens when the number is one?

Comment: @Sywester - agree. The OP should consider a tutorial like Practical Commmon Lisp or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a function in common lisp you can use the `defun` operator:

```
(defun signal-error (msg)
   (error msg))
```

Now you can call it like so:

```
(signal-error "This message will be signalled as the error message")
```

Then you can insert it in your code like this:

```
(print "Enter number") 
(setq number (read)) ;; <- note that you made a syntax error here.
(cond ((< 1 number) (print "Okay"))
      ((> 1 number) (signal-error "Number is smaller than 1."))))
```

In your question you are asking about a `method`. Methods operate on classes. For example imagine you have two classes `human` and `dog`:

```
(defclass human () ())
(defclass dog () ())
```

To create a method specific for each class you use `defmethod`:

```
(defmethod greet ((thing human))
  (print "Hi human!"))

(defmethod greet ((thing dog))
  (print "Wolf-wolf dog!"))
```

Let's create two instances for each class:

```
(defparameter Anna (make-instance 'human))
(defparameter Rex (make-instance 'dog))
```

Now we can greet each living being with the same method:

```
(greet Anna) ;; => "Hi human"
(greet Rex)  ;; => "Wolf-wolf dog!"
```

The process of common lisp knowing which method to execute is called "Dynamic dispatch". Basically it matches the given argument's classes to the `defmethod` definitions.

But I have no idea why you need methods in your code example.

Here is how I would write the code if I was you:

```
;; Let's wrap the code in a function so we can call it
;; as much as we want
(defun get-number-from-user ()
  (print "Enter number: ")
  ;; wrapping the number in a lexical scope is a good
  ;; programming style. The number variable is not
  ;; needed outside the function.
  (let ((number (read)))
    ;; Here we check if the number satisfies our condition and
    ;; call this function again if not.
    (cond ((< number 1) (print "Number is less than 1")
                        (get-number-from-user))
          ((> number 1) (print "Ok.")))))
```

I would suggest you read "The Land of Lisp". It is great book for beginners.

Comment: Yes, but there is already an implicit `progn` after the test in `cond` so this one is superfluous. Also, you might need a `finish-output` to be sure the prompt is displayed before asking for an input.

Comment: Thanks! It is good to also learn stuff when you try to help other people learn stuff! I corrected the `progn`. I will now familiarise myself with `finish-output`.

Comment: I sometimes get comments like this too, it certainly helps.

Comment: Do you mean `defclass` and not `class`?

Comment: Whoops. Corrected.